# Referencia a objeto no establecida

Tags: visual-studio, null

alguien por favor me podría ayudar con este error:

***System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo.Vehiculos.primaryGroup.get devolvió null.***

```
public string Ciudad 
{
 get { return city.name == null ? string.Empty : city.name; } 
 } 
namespace BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo { 
public class City 
{ 
  public int id { get; set; } 
  public string name { get; set; } 
  public object code { get; set; } } 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el código que produce ese error, te sugiero revisar [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, le echaré un vistazo, aquí te dejo el código:


public string Ciudad
        {
            get { return city.name == null ? string.Empty : city.name; }
        }




////////


namespace BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo
{
    public   class City
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object code { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Ok, es la definición de BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo pero debe haber un lugar donde tratas de obtener el valor de primaryGroup.get, en esa clase esta el problema, podrías agregar ese código.